# Flutter Authentication signOut - uid waas called null error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I'm logging out of the application with authentication, but I still get uid null error

This is my signOut method

```
 Future<bool> signOut() async {
try {
  await _auth.signOut(); 
  _user = null;
  return true;
} catch (e) {
  return false;
}
```

}

This is my widget.I can log out successfully, but when switching to the next page it gives uid error and switches

```
actions: <Widget>[
        PopupMenuButton<String>(
          onSelected: (value) async {
            switch (value) {
              case 'Çıkış Yap':
               //problem here
                var  provider =  Provider.of<AuthServices>(context, listen: false);
                await provider.signOut(); 
                 Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GirisEkrani()));
                break;
              case 'Profil Ayarları':
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ProfilGuncellemeEkrani()));
                break;
            }
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return {'Profil Ayarları', 'Çıkış Yap'}.map((String choice) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        ),
      ],
```

Error
The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid

Comment: I don't see any `.uid` in the code you shared. Are you sure the error comes from this code?

Comment: When ı delete this part the problem is solved. 
var  provider =  Provider.of<AuthServices>(context, listen: false);
await provider.signOut();
And the only code part on the login screen 
var myAut =Provider.of<AuthServices>(context,listen: false);
await myAut.signInUserWithEmailandPassword(_email.toString(), _sifre);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the user's `uid` in the `GirisEkrani` widget.

You should remove any reference to the `uid` in there since the user is already signed out and you've set the `_user` variable in your provider to null.

Comment: When ı delete this part the problem is solved. 
var provider = Provider.of<AuthServices>(context, listen: false); await provider.signOut(); 
And the only code part on the login screen 
var myAut =Provider.of<AuthServices>(context,listen: false); await myAut.signInUserWithEmailandPassword(_email.toString(), _sifre);

Comment: Please add the complete code for the Provider and the Login Screen